# Difference between \paragraph and \subparagraph in scrreprt?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, koma-script, sections-paragraphs

I'm using `scrreprt` for writing and (at least for me without any typographic education) I don't see any difference between a section typed as `\paragraph` or `\subparagraph`.

My **questions**:
Is there a difference between the two, and if "no", why not?
What about the spacing before `\paragraph`s in this class? I know that KOMA-Script is very carefully designed (and maybe some of my settings have modified something which they shouldn't), but in my PhD thesis document it seems to me that the spaces before `\(sub)paragraph` are relatively large.

I built a quite lengthy example, as the `blindtext` package does not seem to use `\subparagraph`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,  halfparskip]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\setlength{\parskip}{10ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one in chapter one}
\subsection{Subsection one of section one in chapter one}

Another paragraph, is it? lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem
lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem.

\paragraph{Paragraph1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\subparagraph{Subparagraph1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\paragraph{Par2} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

\paragraph{Par3} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
\subparagraph{SubPar1} Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
\subparagraph{SubPar1} At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

\paragraph{Par3} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

\minisec{minisec1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing "OR the emperor's new clothes" from your title. (I've also added some capitalization.) Hope that's OK.

Comment: @Hendrik: feel free! :-) Sorry, the sub-title was just some pseudo poetic mood after 5 h of sleep in the last 2 days and absolutely not necessary....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a [known bug in KOMA](https://groups.google.com/group/de.comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/734e28e161f3ffd/716a82ea1983c100?hl=de&ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=koma+subparagraph+author%3aschwarz#716a82ea1983c100): I think you're supposed to see that subparagraphs' headings are indented, but you don't, since they're typeset `\raggedright`.

Comment: thanks, you're right. However, the proposed solution only works if the document class option halfparskip is not active, because halfparskip removes all indents and therefore sabotages the workaround :-( [BTW I must say, that the original solution with the indented \subparagraphs is not one which looks very pretty in my eyes... but I'm just a philistine without typographic education] So I'll just try to get along _without_ subparagraphs.

Comment: Meanwhile, the bug has been fixed long ago.