# Is italic + less-space formatting of \subparagraph typographically sensible?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting, koma-script, sections-paragraphs

As discussed in [Difference between \paragraph and \subparagraph in scrreprt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13479/difference-between-paragraph-and-subparagraph-in-scrreprt), my formatting does not make a difference between `\paragraph`, as the proposed [workaround](https://groups.google.com/group/de.comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/734e28e161f3ffd/716a82ea1983c100?hl=de&ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=koma+subparagraph+author:schwarz#716a82ea1983c100) does have no effect, if the option `halfparskip` is active (and I want to use it).

(example see below)

My **questions**:
What do you think about changing the `\subparagraph`so that it's title is not fat, but just italic?
And what about removing the skip above a `\subparagraph`, so that it remains visually attached to the text block before?

*I tried to show how both options could look like in a very quick and dirty example (see below), as I don't know how to redefine the `\subparagraph` properly.*

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,  halfparskip
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\newcommand{\textblock}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Paragraph1} \textblock

\subparagraph{Subparagraph1} \textblock

\textblock

\subsubsection*{now with fixed subparagraph:}

\hspace{\parindent}\hspace{\parindent} 
\makeatletter 
\newlength{\myindent} 
\setlength{\myindent}{\parindent} 
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\myindent}% 
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}% 
  {-1em}% 
  {\raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@subparagraph}% 
} 

\paragraph{Par2}    \textblock

\subparagraph{SubPar2}  \textblock

\subsubsection*{What would you think about that?}

\paragraph{Par3}
\textblock
\\\emph{SubPar3} \hspace{1mm} \textblock

\subsubsection*{\dots or that?}

\paragraph{Par4}
\textblock\smallskip
\\\emph{SubPar4} \hspace{1mm} \textblock


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is obviously a matter of taste, and distinguishing the typographic appearance of six sectional levels (or seven with `\part`) is problematic in any case. That said, I suggest the following:

- Switching from bold to italic font for `\subparagraph` is acceptable (and may be less irritating than an indented sectioning heading). However, you should use KOMA-script's default font family for headings, i.e. sans-serif. Use the `\setkomafont` macro to do so.
- I wouldn't remove the skip before `\subparagraph`. If you want to visually attach a text block to the one before, there's no reason to use a sectioning command in the first place.

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,halfparskip]{scrreprt}

  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

  \newcommand{\textblock}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}

  \makeatletter 
  \newlength{\myindent} 
  \setlength{\myindent}{\parindent} 
  \renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}% 
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}% 
    {-1em}% 
    {\raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@subparagraph}% 
  } 
  \makeatother

  \setkomafont{subparagraph}{\normalfont\sffamily\itshape}

  \begin{document}

  \subsubsection*{Here's my take}

  \textblock

  \paragraph{Paragraph} \textblock

  \textblock

  \subparagraph{Subparagraph} \textblock

  \textblock

  \end{document}
  ```